# Best way to map simple values

Tags: java, dictionary, coding-style

I have a question about mapping Long value to another Long value and the best way to achieve that.

I have to map left values to right values just right before writing data to database.

- 3 => 70
- 8 => 12
- 1 => 45

Is there any "best way"? I was thinking about static map where the left Long will be a key and a right would be a value, and I have just to get a value corresponding to a given key.

Is it good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options: an associative container, or an array.  If the input values are all within a small range and performance is very important, you could use an array.  Otherwise you may as well use a map as you said.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Zwinck points out, a map is generally fine for this type of thing. The cost of mapping from one Long to another is trivial & going to be dwarfed by the network latency of writing to a database (so don't use a primitive arrray :).

**Open for extension, but closed for modification**

I think it's probably more import for you to consider what happens if the mappings change or you need to add another one. In line with SOLID principles (and in particular [open-closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)), it should be possible to modify the mappings without changing the class.

In practice you should make sure you can read the mappings (initially,on demand or periodically) from an external source (e.g. a property file, db, NoSQL cache).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Cheat Sheet]
Use map and pass initial capacity to constructor if you know the size of your key-value pairs.Choose implementation of map carefully depending upon concurrency/ordering requirements as per [source](http://www.sergiy.ca/guide-to-selecting-appropriate-map-collection-in-java/).